# Syntax error in sproc with CTE inside a Try and Transaction block

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

Using: SQL Server 2019, SSMS 19.2, Visual Studio 2022 Database Project
My update statement works by itself and does the right thing. But when I put it in the template I'm supposed to use, which supports multiple DML statements and error logging, it fails to compile and I get:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure tblJobDetails_StoneLocal, Line 10 [Batch Start Line 0]
> Incorrect syntax near 'cteSlabCounts'.

In Visual Studio data project I get the unhelpful:

> Error SQL46005: Expected MARK but encountered cteSlabCounts instead.

Can you help me understand why I get the error? Are CTEs not supported in Try and Transaction blocks?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[tblJobDetails_StoneLocal](
@JobID int
, @StoneID int
)
as
BEGIN
   BEGIN TRY
      BEGIN TRANSACTION

         with cteSlabCounts(JobID, StoneID, CountTotal, Count_O_X, Count_R_@X) as (
            select JobID
               , StoneID
               , CountTotal = count(sd.SlabDetailID)
               , Count_O_X = sum(case when sd.OrderStage = 'X' then 1 else 0 end)
               , Count_R_@X = sum(case when sd.Received in ('@', 'X') then 1 else 0 end)
            from dbo.tblSlabDetails sd
            group by JobID, StoneID
         )
         --select * from cteSlabCounts where JobID = @JobID and StoneID = @StoneID;
         update dbo.tblJobDetails
         set StoneLocal = 1
            from dbo.tblJobDetails jd
            inner join cteSlabCounts sc on sc.JobID = jd.JobID and sc.StoneID = jd.CounterTopID
            where sc.JobID = @JobID and sc.StoneID = @StoneID and sc.Count_O_X = sc.CountTotal and sc.Count_R_@X = sc.CountTotal

      COMMIT TRANSACTION
      
      --Return the affected record(s)?
      select JobDetailID from dbo.tblJobDetails where JobID = @JobID and CounterTopID = @StoneID;
      --return 0;

   END TRY
   BEGIN CATCH   
      IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;

      --OMITTED: Write Exception to Trace.

      THROW
   END CATCH
END
```

Ran the statement in isolation: works.
Copy/paste into template, run it, and get error message indicating that the CTE cannot be used here.

Comment: Missing `;` terminators on all the statements, which is deprecated. `WITH` **requires** the previous statement to be terminated. `THROW` **must** be terminated. Side notes: the transaction is completely unnecesary because it's only one statement, ergo the conditional rollback is also unnecessary. You might as well use an XEvent trace to get error information, then you don't need custom traces. Consider using the `OUTPUT` clause instead of a separate `SELECT`, to get affected rows.

Comment: Putting it this way: at the moment your statements read into the compiler like this: `BEGIN TRY; BEGIN TRANSACTION with; cteSlabCounts(....`